# apache httpd limit server-status to localhost

Tags: apache

We have a rewrite rule to point server-status request to a file containing the words "Apache up"
    
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule server-status  .Status/${HOST}-status [L]
    
We now want to enable the server-status provided by mod_status and make it available to localhost only. To avoid confusion we have defined it as

    SetHandler server-status
    Order Deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

The above does enable /Server-Status, but it is still available to external hosts.  We have defined virtual server so I have included the stanza inside the VirtualHost block, but Server-Status is still generally available.

Any ideas as to way Server-Status is not being allowed by localhost only?

Comment: Share a configuration snippet, please; it is a bad practise to ask such a question without any actual config file excerpt :-(

Comment: Here is the stanza from inside the virtual host def
<VirtualHost *:16488>
    SSLEngine on
<Location /Server-Status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #Require host localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

I have tried with Require host loclhost instead of allow from
Server-Status is still availiable from other hosts